# Will this Windows 8 installation work?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, reinstall

I've currently got a Windows XP / Ubuntu 10.04 dual boot, and both OSes are a mess. I want to take advantage of Microsoft's Windows 8 upgrade offer, and make an installer USB stick.

After making the USB, I want to nuke the hard drive (all partitions), install Windows 8 clean, and then, from Windows, install the latest version of Ubuntu.

Will this work, or, more specifically, will the Windows 8 USB let me install (bearing in mind it's an upgrade), if it detects the hard drive it's installing to is completely blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, windows installation only required when you are purchasing update, and not required after you got your key and installation files. You have to burn your iso or whatever you get after you upgrade to flash drive, and then you can drop your partitions, and install windows and ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it will work, a few guys that i work with actually took advantage of the upgrade offer and then did a clean install exactly like you want to!